# Matlab: Remove diagonal from matrix and reform

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I would like to remove the diagonal of the following matrix;

```
 [0 1 1
  0 0 0
  0 1 0]
```

and put this in a vector as such

```
[1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

Is there a one-way function to do this?
Most other solutions I found on Stack Overflow delete all zeros.

Comment: Is it always going to be a square matrix or can dimensions be different?

Answer (score 7):

If two lines are fine...

```
x = x.'; %'// transpose because you want to work along 2nd dimension first
result = x(~eye(size(x))).'; %'// index with logical mask to remove diagonal
```

Comment: It's as simple as that!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why the transpose? I can see that it works by testing, but the `~eye` makes a mask over the original `x` as far as I can see. Does the second line of code use linear indices in column-major order?

Comment: The first transpose is because the OP wants the result returned row major but indexing with `~eye(size(x))` returns column major. The second transpose is because the OP wants a row vector instead of a column vector that is returned by the logical mask.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an almost one-liner -

```
[m,n] =  size(x);
x(setdiff(reshape(reshape(1:numel(x),m,n).',1,[]),1:m+1:numel(x),'stable'))
```

And I will put up my *fav* [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) here -

```
xt = x.';    %//'
[m,n] =  size(x);
out = xt(bsxfun(@ne,(1:n)',1:m)).'
```

Sample run -

```
>> x
x =
    52    62    37    88
    23    68    98    91
    49    40     4    79
>> [m,n] =  size(x);
>> x(setdiff(reshape(reshape(1:numel(x),m,n).',1,[]),1:m+1:numel(x),'stable'))
ans =
    62    37    88    23    98    91    49    40    79
>> xt = x.';
>> xt(bsxfun(@ne,(1:n)',1:m)).'
ans =
    62    37    88    23    98    91    49    40    79
```